# Reduction of only double bonds

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction

In the conversion shown below I need to find B . Initially I thought of protecting the carbonyl group using ethylene glycol and then carry out reduction of double bonds using hydrogenation but it is required to be a single reagent and cannot be multi step. What are the other ways in which it can be done?

[image]

Comment: You're overthinking. Usual reagents are selective enough here, so no protecting is needed.

Comment: Hydrogenation under relatively low pressure will do this without touching the ketone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a normal hydrogenation reaction(H2,Pd) under low pressures as suggested by @Waylander. Alternatively you can use the [Wilkinson's catalyst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson%27s_catalyst) which also is a way to do catalytic hydrogenation but is capable of only reducing the double bond.